# DialogFlow event

Tags: events, parameters, dialogflow-es

I am having troubles sending a parameterized event from the api. The DF response is not the one that I expect. The event seems to call the intention correctly, but it doesn't pass the parameters to it. When I test the request with the DialogFlow API console, it works correctly.

## JS Code - DetectIntent API

Using npm : dialogflow 1.2.0

```js
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({projectId, credentials}); 
const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId + update.sender.id);
const body_req = {
  session: sessionPath,            
  queryInput: {
    event: {
      name: '01_EVENT_USER',
      parameters: {
        fullname:'Bruno'
      },  
      languageCode: languageCode,
    }
  }            
};

sessionClient.detectIntent(body_req).then(response => { 
    console.log('Request : ', JSON.stringify(body_req));
    console.log('Response : ', JSON.stringify(response));
}, function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
```

### Request and Response

```
#CONSOLE LOG - REQUEST
{
   "session":"projects/PROJECT-xxxxxxxxxxxx/agent/sessions/PROJECTXXXX-bb97ab4d-bc98-4c32-88cc-bfbc3fcd4d50",
   "queryInput":{
      "event":{
         "name":"01_EVENT_USER",
         "parameters":{
            "fullname":"Bruno"
         },
         "languageCode":"es-419"
      }
   }
}


#CONSOLE LOG - RESPONSE

[
  {
    "responseId": "78bf0e26-9d1d-4b54-9f84-02d69979251d-19db3199",
    "queryResult": {
      "fulfillmentMessages": [
        {
          "platform": "PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED",
          "text": {
            "text": [
              ""
            ]
          },
          "message": "text"
        }
      ],
      "outputContexts": [],
      "queryText": "01_EVENT_USER",
      "speechRecognitionConfidence": 0,
      "action": "",
      "parameters": {
        "fields": {
          "event_param_01": {
            "stringValue": "",
            "kind": "stringValue"
          }
        }
      },
      "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
      "fulfillmentText": "",
      "webhookSource": "",
      "webhookPayload": null,
      "intent": {
        "inputContextNames": [],
        "events": [],
        "trainingPhrases": [],
        "outputContexts": [],
        "parameters": [],
        "messages": [],
        "defaultResponsePlatforms": [],
        "followupIntentInfo": [],
        "name": "projects/PROJECT-xxxxxxxxxxxx/agent/intents/4e4c0355-1738-41c3-b0b8-7b2c6a59e120",
        "displayName": "test param",
        "priority": 0,
        "isFallback": false,
        "webhookState": "WEBHOOK_STATE_UNSPECIFIED",
        "action": "",
        "resetContexts": false,
        "rootFollowupIntentName": "",
        "parentFollowupIntentName": "",
        "mlDisabled": false
      },
      "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
      "diagnosticInfo": null,
      "languageCode": "es",
      "sentimentAnalysisResult": null
    },
    "webhookStatus": null,
    "outputAudio": {
      "type": "Buffer",
      "data": []
    },
    "outputAudioConfig": null
  },
  null,
  null
]
```

**Images**

1. [Dialog Flow Console API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtMFg.png)
2. [Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJPpJ.png)

## 1) Intent Edited

I changed the Intent, according to the Prisoner's recommendation and didn't work, the event reach the intention but not the parameter.

1. [Intent Edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTmsf.png)

### Response

```
[
   {
      "responseId":"b0f4a3a9-dd67-49dc-9d80-1c4262ac39e9-19db3199",
      "queryResult":{
         "fulfillmentMessages":[
            {
               "platform":"PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED",
               "text":{
                  "text":[
                     "Hola #01_EVENT_USER.fullname"
                  ]
               },
               "message":"text"
            }
         ],
         "outputContexts":[

         ],
         "queryText":"01_EVENT_USER",
         "speechRecognitionConfidence":0,
         "action":"",
         "parameters":{
            "fields":{

            }
         },
         "allRequiredParamsPresent":true,
         "fulfillmentText":"Hola #01_EVENT_USER.fullname",
         "webhookSource":"",
         "webhookPayload":null,
         "intent":{
            "inputContextNames":[

            ],
            "events":[

            ],
            "trainingPhrases":[

            ],
            "outputContexts":[

            ],
            "parameters":[

            ],
            "messages":[

            ],
            "defaultResponsePlatforms":[

            ],
            "followupIntentInfo":[

            ],
            "name":"projects/PROJECT-XXXXXXXXX/agent/intents/4e4c0355-1738-41c3-b0b8-7b2c6a59e120",
            "displayName":"test param",
            "priority":0,
            "isFallback":false,
            "webhookState":"WEBHOOK_STATE_UNSPECIFIED",
            "action":"",
            "resetContexts":false,
            "rootFollowupIntentName":"",
            "parentFollowupIntentName":"",
            "mlDisabled":false
         },
         "intentDetectionConfidence":1,
         "diagnosticInfo":null,
         "languageCode":"es",
         "sentimentAnalysisResult":null
      },
      "webhookStatus":null,
      "outputAudio":{
         "type":"Buffer",
         "data":[

         ]
      },
      "outputAudioConfig":null
   },
   null,
   null
]
```

## 2) Intent Edited (Simple)

Renamed the event to reduce the complexity, but the behaviour is the same.

1. [Simple Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUiDc.png)
2. Code

```js
          const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({projectId, credentials}); 
          const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId + update.sender.id);
          const body_req = {
            session: sessionPath,            
            queryInput: {
              event: {
                name: 'eventuser',
                parameters: {
                  fullname:'Bruno'
                },  
                languageCode: languageCode,
              }
            }            
          };

          sessionClient.detectIntent(body_req).then(response => {
            console.log('Request : ', JSON.stringify(body_req));
            console.log('Response : ', JSON.stringify(response));
          }, function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
```

### Response

```
[
   {
      "responseId":"a53732b8-bed0-4ae8-8858-81399f7b58e5-19db3199",
      "queryResult":{
         "fulfillmentMessages":[
            {
               "platform":"PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED",
               "text":{
                  "text":[
                     "Hola #eventuser.fullname"
                  ]
               },
               "message":"text"
            }
         ],
         "outputContexts":[

         ],
         "queryText":"eventuser",
         "speechRecognitionConfidence":0,
         "action":"",
         "parameters":{
            "fields":{

            }
         },
         "allRequiredParamsPresent":true,
         "fulfillmentText":"Hola #eventuser.fullname",
         "webhookSource":"",
         "webhookPayload":null,
         "intent":{
            "inputContextNames":[

            ],
            "events":[

            ],
            "trainingPhrases":[

            ],
            "outputContexts":[

            ],
            "parameters":[

            ],
            "messages":[

            ],
            "defaultResponsePlatforms":[

            ],
            "followupIntentInfo":[

            ],
            "name":"projects/apex-way-ar-dev-hgjgyp/agent/intents/4e4c0355-1738-41c3-b0b8-7b2c6a59e120",
            "displayName":"test param",
            "priority":0,
            "isFallback":false,
            "webhookState":"WEBHOOK_STATE_UNSPECIFIED",
            "action":"",
            "resetContexts":false,
            "rootFollowupIntentName":"",
            "parentFollowupIntentName":"",
            "mlDisabled":false
         },
         "intentDetectionConfidence":1,
         "diagnosticInfo":null,
         "languageCode":"es",
         "sentimentAnalysisResult":null
      },
      "webhookStatus":null,
      "outputAudio":{
         "type":"Buffer",
         "data":[

         ]
      },
      "outputAudioConfig":null
   },
   null,
   null
]
```

Comment: There are a few things that would help us help you debug what is going on, and it would be great if you could update your question to include them. While you show some of your code, you're not actually showing what you are doing with `body_req`. It would also be great if, instead of the screen shot from the console, you could include the text from the request and response frames (unless that is the text which you include before that, which wasn't clear). a screen shot of the Intent you expected to be matched would also help a lot.

Comment: I have added the requested code as well as an image of the Intent configuration. The request and the response are exactly the output text from the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Dialogflow's v2 API uses gRPC. You'll need a jsonToStructProto method to convert your JavaScript object to a proto struct.

Here is the sample for your code:

```js
          const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({projectId, credentials}); 
          const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId + update.sender.id);
          const body_req = {
            session: sessionPath,            
            queryInput: {
              event: {
                name: 'eventuser',
                parameters:structjson.jsonToStructProto({fullname: 'Bruno'}),  //Dialogflow's v2 API uses gRPC. You'll need a jsonToStructProto method to convert your JavaScript object to a proto struct.
                languageCode: languageCode,
              }
            }            
          };
```

Comment: Ran into this issue today using `google-cloud/dialogflow-cx@2.15` npm package even though Dialogflow is configured to use V3. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that your Intent is configured with both an Event and with *phrase parameters*. If you're specifying an Event, you don't need specify the parameters in this way.

I don't know for sure, but I wouldn't be surprised that by specifying parameters, the system is then trying to match an empty input against the parameters and failing.

You can omit the parameter section completely.

To [specify event parameters in your reply](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-actions-parameters#event) you would use the format

```
#event-name.parameter-name
```

So your response section would have something like

```
Hola #01_EVENT_USER.fullname
```

**Update** after you've done the above.

It sounds like we're on the right track, at least, since it is now *detecting* the right Intent. But you're right, it doesn't sound like it is handling the Event or the Event Parameters correctly.

The first thing I would try would be to change the event name to something simpler - have letters up front, no underscores, and use all lowercase. Perhaps something like

```
eventuser
```

And see if that works. If it does, try some variants to see where the issue might be. (My guess is that it is the numbers up front that are causing problems, but that is a guess. Start with it as simple as you can, and introduce complexity to see.)

Comment: I changed the Intent, according your recommendation and didn't work, the event reach the intention but not the parameter. The request is the same. I uploaded an image of the edited intent.

Comment: Sounds like we've had some progress, at least. I've updated my answer with some additional things to try.

Comment: I find it very strange that from the google console, the parameter arrives correctly, but not from the js code. I suspect the problem may be in the npm package or the detectIntent method. but I'm not sure.